# ActionCable too fast for DOM update

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, settimeout, actioncable

I have a situation where I am updating a the DOM with information from a 3rd party website at the same time that I am creating an object on the backend with ajax. Sometimes the ajax call returns slower than the separate job responds through ActionCable.

On the front-end I'm rendering the 3rd party results but when the DOM hasn't been updated I end up with an un-updatable DOM. Is there another way to handle a delay other than just with a setTimeout?  Because if for some reason I don't wait long enough, the DOM update will still fail.

EDIT: Code of what I'm trying to do.

```
  connectPosts: function connectPosts(){
    var self = this;
    if (!webSockets) { return }
    App.cable.subscriptions.create({
      channel_id: channel_id,
      channel: 'PostsChannel'
    },{
      received: function(data){
        var $element = $('#' + data['object_type'] + '_' + data['object_id'] + ' .container');
        if($element.length == 0)
          setTimeout(function(data){self.buildElement(data)}, 1000, data);
        else
          self.buildElement(data);
      }
    });

  },
  buildElement: function buildElement(data){
    var $element = $('#' + data['object_type'] + '_' + data['object_id'] + ' .container');
    var content = HandlebarsTemplates['posts/element'](data);

    $element.html(content);

    if($element.find('.author-' + self.currentUser.id)){
      $element.find('a').show();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: do you have some code?

Comment: you can use success function of ajax. It would be good if you can provide some code for us.